# ¿Como saber cuando capturan la pantalla de mi pagina web?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con html,laravel,php, javascript, jquery y ajax el problema es que quiero saber cuando le tomen captura de pantalla a mi pagina web y mandar una alerta por correo electrónico.

he buscado información pero no encuentro nada relacionado, entonces no he probado nada.

hay alguna manera de hacerlo o es posible hacerlo?

de ante mano gracias.

Comment: Creería que no es posible, una captura de pantalla es algo propio del SO y ningún browser debe tener permisos para reconocer otro programa que se esté ejecutando. Lo que se me ocurre, es que por ahí puedes identificar cuando se presiona la tecla de **Imprimir Pantalla** y ejecutar una función ahí pero eso no quiere decir que haya capturado la pantalla necesariamente.

Comment: Tienes razón no lo había pensado así, entonces estaba buscando mal la información muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Me temo que lo que intentas hacer no es posible. La captura de pantalla la realiza el usuario mediante una llamada a la API del sistema operativo. El proceso que gestiona el navegador web no es consciente de la realización de estas llamadas por lo que no es posible, en principio, capturarlas.

Podría pensarse que se puede capturar la pulsación de la tecla de captura de pantalla pero:

1. Esta tecla no desencadena eventos asociados a teclas como keypress.
2. La pulsación de esta tecla no es la única forma de ordenar una captura de pantalla.

Por lo general, puedes intentar tener cierto control de lo que ocurre en el cliente, pero la dueña y señora de lo que ocurre es la máquina del cliente.